# Using cross correlation and an uncorrelated eigenvector basis to minimize exposure

Tags: pca, eigenvalues, cross-correlation

I have the following problem:

We are looking at stock market data and have a historic price dataset $X$ with two stock types:
\begin{equation}
X = \begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & x_2
\end{bmatrix} 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & |\epsilon_1 + 1| \\
2 & |\epsilon_2 + 1| \\
\vdots & \vdots \\
n_s & |\epsilon_{n_s} + 1|
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $n_s = 100$ is the number of observations with the last observation being the most recent one, and $\epsilon$ are randomly drawn normalized numbers around 0. Furthermore we have a second stock market price dataset $Y$, which only contains one stock type:
\begin{equation}
Y = y_1 = x_1 + x_2 
\end{equation}

Given a fixed set of stocks of the types described by $X$, the overall goal is to determine the amount of stocks needed of the types described by $Y$ to minimize the overall exposure of all stocks.

**Attempted solution**

The first thing I want to do in order to solve this problem is to correctly calculate the exposure. (By exposure we mean the amount of money that is dependent on the variations in stock prices)
Suppose that the stocks I have are: 1 of $x_1$, 2 of $x_2$ and -1 of $y_1$. In this case the overall exposure should clearly just be the exposure of 1 $x_2$ stock since the rest cancel out.
However I am unable to get this expected result and I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

From these two datasets I create the composite dataset $Z = \begin{bmatrix} X & Y \end{bmatrix}$.

I compute the Pearson correlation matrix for these 3 variables:
\begin{equation}
C = \begin{bmatrix}
corr(x_1, x_1) & corr(x_1, x_2) & corr(x_1,y_1) \\
corr(x_2, x_1) & corr(x_2, x_2) & corr(x_2,y_1) \\
corr(y_1, x_1) & corr(y_1, x_2) & corr(y_1,y_1)
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -0.0541 & 0.9996 \\
-0.0541 & 1 & -0.0277 \\
0.9996 & -0.0277 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Interestingly, I note that even though $y_1$ and $x_2$ are actually correlated they end up having a lower Pearson correlation than the uncorrelated $x_1, x_2$.

I use the orthonormal eigenvector basis, $V$, to transform my correlated variables to a set of uncorrelated variables.
Hence $\tilde{Z} = Z V$.

In the uncorrelated basis I would expect the exposure to just be the $L_1$ norm of the combined value of all stocks:

\begin{equation}
E = || z V \odot p V ||_1
\end{equation}
where $z = [1, 2, -1]$ is the number of stocks I have, and $p = [100, 2.56, 102.56]$ is the unit price of each stock. $\odot$ is the elementwise product.

The exposure I find doing this is:
\begin{align}
E &= || \begin{bmatrix} 2.67 & -0.11 \end{bmatrix} ||_1 \\
E &= 2.78
\end{align}
Interestingly enough, the result I would expect is exactly $2.67-0.11 = 2.56$ which is the value of 1 $x_2$ stock. So this seems to me to indicate that I am on the right track but I am still doing something wrong.